# How can I display the email of the user who has booked

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm creating a small "time slot" booking application.

But I'm having some problems displaying which user, that has booked a specific timeslot.

The idea is, to have a link called Reserve, and when there are no bookings, a text saying: Booked by: [The users email]

The way is display my time links is like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE room_id= '".$room_id."' AND eventDate='".$dateToCompare."'AND timeslot = $time;";

    $result = $db->mysqli->query ( $sql );

    if (mysqli_num_rows ( $result ) == 0) {
        echo "<a href='" . $_SERVER ['PHP_SELF'] . "?id=" . $room_id . "?month=" . $month . "&day=" . $day . "&year=" . $year . "&t={$time}&v=true&f=true&reserved=true'><h3 style='color: rgb(255,0,0);'>Reserve</h3></a>";
    } else {
        echo  $user->getEmail();
        while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array ( $result ) ) {
            echo "<br />";
        }
    }
```

As you can see, I echo my `function $user->getEmail();` if there are any bookings.

I've tried to do this is my function.

```
public function getEmail() {
            $str = "SELECT bookings.*, users.email AS booking_email FROM bookings, users WHERE bookings.user_id = users.id";
            $result = $this->db->mysqli->query ($str);
            $string = "";
            while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc () ) {
                $string .= $row ['booking_email'];
            }
            return $string;
        }
```

But as you would properbly imagine, that echoes out every single email in my database.

I¨m thinking that I need something more in my sql query?

You can see my foreign key relation here:

[image]

I hope some of you can point me in the right direction. And please tell me if I need to provide more code.

EDIT:

This is how I create my bookings:

```
if (isset ( $_GET ['reserved'] )) {
    $sqlreserve = "INSERT INTO bookings (user_id, room_id, eventDate, timeslot) VALUES ('" . $user_id . "','" . $room_id . "','" . $dateToCompare . "','" . intval ( $_GET ['t'] ) . "');";
    $resultreserve = $db->mysqli->query ( $sqlreserve );
    echo $resultreserve;
}
```

Comment: What exactly you want to get in return with your getEmail() function? I assume this is your case right? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/24a2b8/1 You get there all bookings with associated email.

Comment: When a room is reserved, I want a to see the email of the user who has reserved the room.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please *explicitly* define your joins, instead of using *implicit* joins.  It makes SQL easier to understand and avoids mistakes.

If you adjust your first SQL statement you can fetch the Users email address with the room availability if it is available.

```
SELECT
    `bookings`.*,
    `users`.`email` AS booking_email
FROM `bookings`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `users`
    ON (`bookings`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`)
WHERE
        `room_id`   = '".$room_id."'
    AND `eventDate` = '".$dateToCompare."'
    AND `timeslot`  = '".$time."'
```